# Is there a real multi-dimension timeseies dataset in which data samples have feature based similarities?

Tags: dataset, time-series, multilabel-classification

I'm looking for real datasets which are multi-dimension time-series and there exist partial similarities between different categories based on some of the features/dimensions.

For example, consider two persons waving, but one is doing that while walking and the other while driving in a car. So their generally they are related to different motion categories,  are different but both are similar according to their arm movements.

Thanks!